# No wireless option Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire laptop, and this is my first experience with Linux. I'm having trouble with the WiFi. There is no option for me to turn wireless on, and there is no list of available networks.

I know similar questions have been asked a lot, but I've been different different answers for the last couple of days and trying the solutions and none of them have worked.

I have Broadcom BCM43228, and I have selected "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)" in the Additional drivers section of the system settings.

My wireless is not soft or hard blocked, my wired internet is working, and my WiFi also works in Windows.

Output of iwconfig:

> ~$ iwconfig
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.`

Output of `sudo modprobe wl`

`~$ sudo modprobe wl
 [sudo] password for zacmerphy: 
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available`

Comment: can you please post the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: I edited my question with it in but I don't know the best way to copy terminal output here I'm sorry

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: sudo modprobe wl ?

Comment: I edited it into the question.